# Calculate a shift from day and time (Solved)

Tags: excel, formula, lookup

I run 2 shifts Monday - Friday, 06.30-15.30 / 15.30-01.30, and two shifts on Saturday & Sunday, 05.30-17.30 / 17.30-05.30.

My data sheet has the 'day' and 'time' as available look ups, how would I write a formula so the cell populates what shift the time and date entry refers to?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bfb9C.png)

Comment: It would be useful to see what the data actually looks like and what the expected result is. Also any formula/code you have tried so far and an explanation of how they fail to achieve the desired goal

Comment: I've added an image link in the post, can you see it?

Comment: Please provide expected output in the shift column so we can understand better what do you want and also help us putting the input data in **Table Markdown format**, you can use the following [Table Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables)

Comment: Hi David, I've updated the attached image so my request makes makes more sence. I run four shifts over the week, days / backs / weekend days / weekend backs. Our machine data systems produce reports that details the first five columns shown, what I'm wanting to do if insert a formula into columa F that will then calculate which shift that row of data refers to. So the first row entry is 09.01 on Wednesday 18/01/23 so it would be 'Days'

Answer (score 0):

Well, I did something similar for 3 shifts like this:

[image]

I used the Solver and it may give you some ideas on how to approach your problem.